# mongoose: how to select sub document by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I Don't know how to select sub document by its own id
I try to use expressjs create REST api, "localhost:3000/api/parent/:parent_id/child/:child_id" the Official Moogose document is [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) and the code is
`var doc = parent.children.id(id);` 
 but is keep returning `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` Or `null` in console.
 here is my expressjs code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/parent');

var ChildSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String
},{collection:"child"});

var ParentSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  child:[ChildSchema]
},{collection:"parent"});

var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', ParentSchema);
//
// var parentA=new Parent({name:"A 123",child:[{name:"A 1"},{name:"A 2"},{name:"A 3"}]});
// var parentB=new Parent({name:"B 123",child:[{name:"B 1"},{name:"B 2"},{name:"B 3"}]});
// var parentC=new Parent({name:"C 123",child:[{name:"C 1"},{name:"C 2"},{name:"C 3"}]});

// parentA.save();
// parentB.save();
// parentC.save();

app.get('/api/parent', function(req, res){
  Parent.find(function(err,data){
    res.json(data);
  });
});

app.get('/api/parent/:parent_id/child/:child_id', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.child_id);
  /*problem here!!!!!*/
  var doc = Parent.child.id(req.params.child_id);
  console.log(doc);
});

app.listen(3000,console.log("localhost:3000"));
```

So how to select sub document by its id, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I can spot is that you are both creating a collection for the subdocument and then embedding the full document in the parent.
I have not really tested that but seems rather odd. Either you embed the document or you reference it to another collection.

So either:

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childSchema]
})
```

Or:

```
var ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String
},
{ collection:"child" });
mongoose.model('Child', ChildSchema);

var ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  children: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child', default: null }]
},
{collection:"parent"});
mongoose.model('Parent', ParentSchema);
```

Finally, the example posted in the mongoose documentation is for the first of the two options.

Comment: Thanks, but after i delete the `{collection:"child"}`  in ChildSchema, console.log  still out put:"   TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined  "  my request is like this:"http://localhost:3000/api/parent/57fe6e26d0505e1974ac0b68/child/57fe6e26d0505e1974ac0b6b"   is this because of the id should be ObjectId?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find the parent document before you can get a child by children.id().

```
app.get('/api/parent/:parent_id/child/:child_id', function(req, res){
  Parent.findById(req.params.parent_id, function(err, parent) {
    console.log(req.params.child_id);
    var doc = parent.child.id(req.params.child_id);
    console.log(doc);
  });
});
```

Also see this http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html for mor info.